# Slider rewinds by default but I want it to be cyclical

Tags: ionic-framework

Ionic slide box images only rewinding by default.But I want  Slider to be cyclical. How to solve it.

I tried to implement jquery slider instead of Ionic slide box . But its not worked properly.

I tried this files to add a header on my index page

```
  <script src="lib/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script> 

  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.nivo.slider.js"></script> 

  <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('#slider').nivoSlider();

        });

  </script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default/default.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />



<div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
            <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider" ng-repeat="club in slider"> 

                  <img ng-src="{{club.url}}"  style='width:100% !important;'  >
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Provide what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had add this code on my controller it working fine for me.

```
        $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.update();
        $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.loop(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Few suggestions if you want to use jQuery with ionic/angularJS:

1. Load your jquery before ionic js and angular js libraries loads.
2. Call jQuery from your controllers for better control over application flow. eg. `$('#slider').nivoSlider();` call it from your controller and put your html in view template of the controller.

It would be great if your can elaborate on the kind of slider you want in your app (I couldn't understand what you mean by `cyclical`).